# How do I change the color of the light emitted by an Irradiance Volume Light Probe in EEVEE?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting, color, lightprobe

I am working with EEVEE right now, and I wanted to use the irradiance Volume Light Probe to create a sort of square shape light. It works pretty well but I can't find the option to change the color of the lighting emitted by it...

Any idea ?

EDIT :

Here is what I am trying to do :

[image]

I am trying to simulate some sort of coral reefs by using a square shape lighting (couldn't figure out  how to change the shape of the spot lamp with blender 2.8 using EEVEE so I decided to use Volume Light Probe). The issue is that I would like to change the color of these fake coral reefs, in order to make them a tiny bit greenish.
If I change the color of the light emitted by the sun (my only source of lighting), I will lose these white reflections on the water.

Comment: Could you maybe clarify what you mean by generated light? I'm pretty sure you must have a light inside the volume to create this effect. Just change the color of the light.

Comment: I edited my post, hope It will be clearer. I feel like I don't really understand how Volume Light Probe is supposed to work...